# what's the time complexity of the number of shots in simulator of qiskit

Tags: qiskit, simulation, qiskit-runtime

One question,
codes as follows:

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
counts = execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=102400).result().get_counts()
```

when my number of shots is 102400, is my time complexity 102400? That means i need Multiply 102400 by the time complexity of the relevant algorithm.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the simulation mode (regular, stabilizer, MPS, etc.) and structure of the circuit. Roughly, if your circuit doesn't have noise or mid-circuit measurements then it's simulated only once, then measurement outcomes are sampled.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, and now could i tell you the next question?you said it's simulated only once. can i think it's only one the circuit needs run, and i can get 102400 results from it? Can you explain why i can get so many results only from one circuit running? Thank you

Comment: You sample the final state vector

Comment: But does 102400 shots mean running the circuit 102400 times？

Comment: No, the simulators runs the circuit once, obtains the final state vector, and samples.

Comment: but in qiskit source code:shots (int): Number of repetitions of each circuit, for sampling. Default: 1024     Is it mean run the circuit many times?